# Mysql: query not giving accurate result with IN clause and inner query

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to get zip codes from zip_id's which are internally stored in companies service table below screens will give you clear idea

**I have wrote this query**
 [image]

**companies service table**
[image]

Please suggest me your valuable views . Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already mentioned your database scheme is not very well designed, it violates even [1st normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form). You'd need another table where you'd store `serv_area_id` and `zip_code` (with possibly multiple rows for a signle `serv_area_id`) and search within this table and eventually join your original table.

Nevertheless, in order to get the result you describe you cannot use the `IN` operator as it operates on a value and multiple values in a form of table (either explicit via nested `SELECT` or enumeration literal `(val1, ..., valN)`). I would try some string matching as illustrated below. However, consider it rather an ugly hack than correct solution(!)

```
SELECT zip FROM cities_extended WHERE (
    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(',', serv_are_zipcodes)
    FROM company_service_areas WHERE ...
) LIKE concat('%(', id, ')%')
```